# How to insert Indian Rupees Symbol in Database (Oracle 10g, MySql 5.0 and Sql Server 2008)?

Tags: database, unicode

How to insert Indian Rupees Symbol in Database (Oracle 10g, MySql 5.0 and Sql Server 2008)?

Actually i had one Table "Currency" , in which 2 field is like "currencyName" and "currencysymbol", so how would i insert new rupees symbol in databse.

Comment: i think you have to wait until it made into the unicode and oracle or any other vendor implement that unicode version in the db products.

Comment: It's not required for the database to recognise the specific Unicode character in order to store it. You would need database support if you wanted the character to sort/match (collate) against other character according to some particular rule, but that hardly seems necessary for a currency symbol.

Comment: @Preet Sangha: rolled back your edit. The OP is specifically asking about the new rupee symbol, which has been recently assigned the code point U+20B9. U+20A8 is the old rupee symbol, with decomposition ‘Rs’.

Comment: @bob - cheers. Should the question be edited to make it more precise too please?

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing special about `₹` (U+20B9 New Rupee symbol), except that, being so new, there is almost zero font support for it. If you've got a database connection that supports Unicode, you can store it just as easily as any other character:

```
INSERT INTO Currency (name, symbol) VALUES ('INR', '₹');
```

(You would want to use NVARCHAR for storage and `N'₹'` in SQL Server.)

If you haven't got a Unicode-safe connection (for example you're using some crap tool like the Windows console) you would have to work around that using eg.

```
VALUES ('INR', CHAR(226, 130, 185))
```

for a UTF-8-collated column in MySQL, or `NCHAR(8377)` for a Unicode column in SQL Server.

Comment: I am trying same but not able to insert in the oracle 11g.

Comment: @eatSleepCode: You'll need to ensure that your tables are stored with `CHARACTER SET UTF8` and the connection to Oracle itself uses `UTF8`. (Or `AL32UTF8` in both cases if you want to also support characters outside trhe Basic Multilingual Plane.)

Answer (score 1):

Not ever done this but can use use [NCHAR (integer_expression )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx)

```
insert into Currency (currencyName, currencysymbol)
values ('Indian Rupee', NCHAR(8425) ) -- 8425 is 20B9 in decimal
```

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Each character has a Unicode that unique it from others, `Indian Rupees Symbol` has it own. so as every other characters you can insert it in yourdatabase, but the most important point is that your `currencysymbol` field in table should be **`NVARCHAR`**

When you are inserting this symbol you have to use its Unicode code like

```
 INSERT INTO Currency ([currencysymbol]) VALUES (N'⃰'); -- dont forget to use **N** before the symbol
```

just make sure that **20B9** is the code for your character

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into  currency values('india','rupee',N'रु'')
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to link to your blog like this. I am removing the link to prevent the post from being deleted as spam. The answer is very short - please post the entire answer on this website.

Answer (score 1):

@Sanju   Its so simple as to insert normal text, first of all you need to download a font from http://cdn.webrupee.com/WebRupee.V2.0.ttf.
Than keep this font file in a folder named 'WebRupee' ok! than copy this code or write your own code as i deed, see

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table><style>
@font-face{font-family: 'WebRupee';
src: url('WebRupee/WebRupee.V2.0.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
.WebRupee{
color:#FF0000;
font-family: 'WebRupee';}
</style>
   <tr>

      <td><input type="text" name="rs"  value="Rs."class="WebRupee"  /></span>
                 </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>

      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                 </td>
                     </tr>
                       </table>
</form>

<?php 
if($_POST['submit']){

  $sql="insert into rs(inr)VALUES('$_POST[rs]')";
  if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      die('Error:'.mysql_error());
   }
        else{
       echo "<script>alert('One Record Added !!!...')</script>";

        mysql_close($con);
        }}

         ?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

We have used nvarchar colum for currencysymbol and insert NCHAR(8377) :

```
insert into Currency (currencyName, currencysymbol)
values ('Indian Rupee', NCHAR(8377) );
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Faculty_First_Name, Faculty_Salary, FORMAT(Faculty_Salary, 'C') AS DollarCurrency_Salary,
CONCAT_WS(N'₹','', Faculty_Salary) AS  IndianRupee
FROM Faculty_Info;