# How to insert Indian Rupee symbol in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle11g

I want to insert Indian Rupee symbol in oracle 11g.

I have tried:

```
insert into currency(name, symbol) values ('rupee', unistr('\20B9'));
```

but its not working.

`SELECT ascii('₹') FROM dual;` it gives ascii value for Rupee symbol but after insert it shows  box in the row.

here you can see

```
SELECT chr(14844601) FROM dual;
```

Comment: maybe it's your client unicode/language/font settings. I'm using foreign language and I can't display it in the sqlplus command line.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879483/how-to-insert-indian-rupees-symbol-in-database-oracle-10g-mysql-5-0-and-sql-se)

Comment: I already checked that question but there is no answer for Oracle.

Comment: Please post definition of `currency` table, charset settings of database and Oracle locale settings on the client. Which client application used to display results? Did you use [`NVARCHAR2` datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3793) for `symbol` field?

Comment: I am using SQL Developer the column datatype is NVARCHAR2. @ThinkJet

Comment: Seems that you just need to change a font in SQL Developer. Check [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b8f8/1)

Comment: Another point is that you must use `nchr` (not `chr`) to work with unicode symbols ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b8f8/4)).

Comment: Not getting how to change the font for SQL developer? @ThinkJet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you just need to change a font in SQL Developer. Check [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b8f8/1).

There are two things wrong in your question text: to get unicode symbol from it's code [`nchr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions091.htm) function must be used instead of [`chr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions019.htm#i76965). Second is that `'₹'` constant string treated as `varchar2` and to properly specify `nvarchar2` constant you [must prepend `N`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm#i1006315) to this literal: `N'₹'` .

To change font just open `Tools -> Preferences ...` menu

[image]

and choose `Code Editor -> Fonts` node. At this page you can select font from `Font Name` dropdown list. Copy and past rupee symbol into `Sample Text` field to quickly see if font are acceptable. 
Arial (on win7) works fine for me:

[image]

This setting changes grid font as well as font in code editor:

[image]

Actions above puts you only to a half of the way to get full rupee symbol support because `select N'₹' from dual` will return only question sign. This is because of query text encoding conversion done between client and server side.
To deal with this issue Oracle [provides ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE environment setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm#CACHHIFE). This setting guides client API to analyze query text for character constants prefixed with `N` and use special internal format to encode such a data on client side before transferring query text to server. Unfortunately SQL Developer uses Thin JDBC API which ignores this environment setting, so adding this environment variable doesn't  solve a problem.

But there are [another way](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm#CHDCBACA) to turn on same behavior with `oracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals` property which acts on a system and connection levels.
To turn this property on, locate `ide.conf` file in `sqldeveloper\ide\bin` directory in SQL Developer installation folder and add this line to the end of a file:

```
AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals=true
```

Save file and restart SQL Developer, all things must work now:

[image]

P.S. Instructions based on SQL Developer Version 3.2,  old versions may have another location of configuration file. E.g. `sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` .