# Page displaying '?', instead of 'é'

Tags: oracle, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I am retriving data from oracle11g and displaying the data on IE8 and IE9 browser, but the couldn't display some special characters (eg. é)

In my webpage, I have explicitly declare 'UTF-8' encoding.

For my tomcat webserver, the server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

I read some other questions in stackflow, they mentioned to also ensure the database connection is using 'UTF-8' too.

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/AppDB" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
        username="foo"
        password="bar"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/      ID_development?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    />
```

The solution given is for mysql. 
**How can i set the encoding if im using oracleDriver?**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AppDB"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ora11"
       username="foo"
       password="bar"
       maxActive="20"
       maxIdle="1000"
       maxWait="-1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198563/232279). Regardless of fact that it's focused on SQL Developer, it contains information about tuning JDBC driver and points out how to properly handle unicode character types in Oracle.

**Update**
Troubles with displaying characters on the client may be caused by wrong `NLS_LANG` settings on the database client (Tomcat in your case). For thin JDBC driver NLS_LANG value derived from java locale settings.
For possible variants you can look through the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079985/nls-lang-setting-for-jdbc-thin-driver/2585394) and check [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17657/global.htm).
If a real source of the problem lies to character set of Oracle database connection, then there are only two possible end points to check: `NLS_LANG` and `oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar` . So you need to examine if both set properly to figure out what is happened.

Comment: Thank you @ThinkJet. The data is stored in the dB successfully, i'm encountering some displaying issue. And i do not have the permission to edit the dB, only the configuration in the web server (tomcat)

Comment: Thank you @ThinkJet. I will use your suggestion to carry on the investigation and update with my finding.