# How to enter the Indian Rupee symbol in MySQL Server 5.1?

Tags: mysql, database, unicode

I am unable to find the exact solution for MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert Indian Rupees Symbol in Database (Oracle 10g, MySql 5.0 and Sql Server 2008)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879483/how-to-insert-indian-rupees-symbol-in-database-oracle-10g-mysql-5-0-and-sql-se)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thing is the column supports by default UTF-8 encoding which consists of 3 bytes. The Indian Rupee Symbol, since it is new has a 4 byte encoding. So we have to change the character encoding to utf8_general_ci by,

```
ALTER TABLE test_tb MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

After executing the above query simply execute the following query to insert the symbol,

```
insert into test_tb values("₹");
```

Ta-Da!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are talking Oracle, yet it is tagged MySQL.  Which do you want?  And what language and/or client tool are you using?

Copy and paste it.  Which Rupee do you like?  `৲ ৳ ૱ ௹ ₨ ꠸`

Probably you want this one:
`UNHEX('E282A8')` = `'₨'`
which is U+20A8 or 8360  in non-MySQL contexts

You need to have `CHARACTER SET utf8` on the table/column.

You need to have done `SET NAMES utf8` (or equivalent) when connecting.

Comment: I need it for MySQL. And this is the rupee symbol I am looking for, '₹'. It's unicode value is U+20B9. I followed your suggestion. always end up with a '?' being stored in the database.

Comment: That's utf8 hex `E282B9`.  When you do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` do you get that?  Or `3F` (which represents `?`)?

Comment: You are asking "how to enter" -- please explain what tool/UI/application/etc you are using.  I would just do `INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUE ('₹')` if I could type (or copy) that character.  (I did a copy to make the previous sentence.)

Comment: I've looked up that character and that unicode in two databases; they don't match.  Do you have a reference for that character/code?

Comment: Here is the link showing more details about the symbol and its unicode, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm . I am using the command line client to insert the value. I tried copy paste and inserted the value with that symbol but when I select from the database I see a '?' symbol denoting that the character is not recognized.

Comment: I accept that 20B9 and ₹ are what you want.  Please provide the `SELECT` you mentioned.  We need to first decide whether the `INSERT` failed or the `SELECT` got the '?'.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest way to do it is, utf8mb4 stores all the symbols**

```
 ALTER TABLE AsinBuyBox CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```